# Coreference Resolution using OpenNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I want to do *"coreference resolution"* using OpenNLP. Documentation from Apache ([Coreference Resolution](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.coref)) doesn't cover how to do *"coreference resolution"*. Does anybody have any docs/tutorial how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is little coreference resolution documentation for OpenNLP at the moment except for [a very short mention of how to run it in the readme](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/README.html#run).

If you're not invested in using OpenNLP, then consider the [Stanford CoreNLP package](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), which includes [a Java example of how to run it,](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage) including how to perform coreference resolution using the package.  It also includes [a page summarizing it's performance, and the papers published on the coreference package](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml).

Answer (score 12):

I recently ran into the same problem and wrote up some blog notes for using OpenNLP 1.5.x tools.  It's a bit dense to copy in its entirety, so [here's a link with more details](http://blog.dpdearing.com/2012/11/making-coreference-resolution-with-opennlp-1-5-0-your-bitch/).

---

At a high level, you need to load the appropriate [OpenNLP coreference model libraries](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.4/english/coref/) and also the [WordNet 3.0 dictionary](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/download/current-version/#nix).  Given those dependencies, initializing the linker object is pretty straightforward:

```
// LinkerMode should be TEST
//Note: I tried LinkerMode.EVAL before realizing that this was the problem
Linker _linker = new DefaultLinker("lib/opennlp/coref", LinkerMode.TEST);
```

Using the Linker, however, is a bit less obvious.  You need to:

1. Break the content down into sentences and the corresponding tokens
2. Create a Parse object for each sentence
3. Wrap each sentence Parse so as to indicate the sentence ordering:

   ```
   final DefaultParse parseWrapper = new DefaultParse(parse, idx);
   ```
4. Iterate over each sentence parse ane use the Linker to get the Mention objects from each parse:

   ```
   final Mention[] extents =
      _linker.getMentionFinder().getMentions(parseWrapper);
   ```
5. Finally, use the Linker to identify the distinct entities across all of the Mention objects:

   ```
   DiscourseEntity[] entities = _linker.getEntities(arrayOfAllMentions);
   ```

Comment: Could you please indicate me how this would be done from the command line? Thank you.

Comment: In the blog you said you load the models using `getResourceAsStream` but at the end didn't describe how you told Linker to load the models using `getResourceAsStream`. How did you actually load the models?

Comment: @justhalf That's actually just a copy+paste error from a previous step on the blog.  The `Linker` takes the path to the coreference models directly, so no need to use `getResourceAsStream`.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Finally! Now that I can contact you, there are few improvements for your blog. First is regarding the use of ParseTool.parseLine. it expects a tokenized text, so you need to tokenize it first before giving to the function. Also, I think the Linker says it wants to have NameFinder been run first in the Parse object to have better result. I still struggle with getting good results, though, somehow I get a pronoun attached to an NP containing appositives, while I prefer only the head NP

Comment: @justhalf - I think `ParseTool.parseLine` expects a `String` sentence and not a token array, so I'm not sure about tokenizing first.  Similarly the `NameFinder` takes a token array and not a `Parse` object, so I'm not sure how that works.  In the future you can always comment on the blog to contact me directly.

Comment: `ParseTool.parseLine` expects a tokenized sentence in form of a String. So the input should be something like "I , the king , work there ( you know ) ."

Comment: @user, I don't directly.  It's needed by the coreference resolution linker